# Sync javascript countdown with server time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I will try my best to explain my problem in a correct english.

I have a global countdown in ajax  which display the timeleft (calculated with server time) with a setinterval.
The aim is to call a function only once when the timeleft  reach some target.

```
$timeLeft = strtotime($wallet->date_upd)- time();
if ($timeLeft <= 3)
{ 
  function() 'this function update or not $wallet->date_upd to add time' 
}
```

As the ajax countdown is global, and due to transfer and rendering delays, the function can be called by several users.. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just validate on server, whether the function has already been called or not? Any user can call your function from client at any time, no matter how hard you'll try to syncronize the time between users.

Comment: I tried to check if the function has been called or not with a bool insert in mysql. But with the delays, the function can still be called more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume that when the timleft is over and your script runs that you also update the `date_upd` to a new time?

In that case you can just do the update and check if there is an affected row.
If another script was faster than the WHERE in the query will not work anymore and the affected_rows will be 0.

```
$new_date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 hours'));

mysql_query("UPDATE wallet SET date_upd = '{$new_date_upd}' WHERE date_upd = '{$wallet->date_upd}'");
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
   // this script is the only one doing this stuff 
}
```

So that should be something working in MySQL.

If you're managing your own server and can install some stuff then I advise you to checkout Redis.io which is a great tool for doing in memory stuff ( like an advanced memcache ) and it can also help you with doing 'locking' in a nice way

Comment: You are my lord ! Thank you